# Java and JavaFXML Jeopardy Program

Tags: java

I am currently working on a JavaFXML Jeopardy game. I realized that I am rewriting a lot of code and am curious of ways to better the code so that it is easier to read and more concise.

I tried making question objects to store in an array, but it seemed as though I was still rewriting a lot of the same code.

Below is an example of a `200 Category Button`

```
@FXML
private void sportsTwoAction(ActionEvent event) { // FILL IN THE BLANK 
    TextInputDialog sportsC2Tid = new TextInputDialog();
    sportsC2Tid.setTitle("Sports ["+score200+"]");
    sportsC2Tid.setHeaderText("In what year were the Las Vegas Golden Knights added to the NHL?");
    sportsC2Tid.setContentText("Please enter your answer as an integer with no spaces (i.e. 2020)");
    // correct answer = 2016
    Optional<String> sportsC2Result = sportsC2Tid.showAndWait();
    if(sportsC2Result.isPresent()){
        userInputAnswer = sportsC2Result.get();
        userInputAnsInt = Integer.parseInt(userInputAnswer);        
        System.out.println("You said: "+userInputAnswer);
        
        if (userInputAnsInt != 2016 || userInputAnswer.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("INCORRECT!");
            sportsTwoBtn.setDisable(true);
            incorrectAlert.setTitle("Sports ["+score200+"]");
            incorrectAlert.setHeaderText("Incorrect!\n No points will be awarded.");
            incorrectAlert.setContentText("Press OK to continue");
            incorrectAlert.showAndWait();
        } else if (userInputAnsInt == 2016) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            sportsTwoBtn.setDisable(true);
            correctAlert.setTitle("Sports [$200]");
            correctAlert.setHeaderText("Correct!\n You've added [$200] to your score!");
            correctAlert.setContentText("Press OK to continue");
            correctAlert.showAndWait();
        }  
    }     
}
```

I am very new to posting on StackOverflow and CodeReview so if there is any information that I left out or clarification needed, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You're hard-coding the answers and questions, which is a crazy way to do it. Not only do you have to recompile your code to make any changes, you would also have to copy-and-paste the logic for each prompt all over the place. Instead, put all of the categories, answers, and questions into a configuration file, and write the code to use the configuration as input.